# React Native: Is it possible to control how long the Launch Image displays on app open?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, loading

In our React Native app, there seem to be different loading stages the app goes through. Generally, when opening from the homescreen:

1) The Launch Image displays. This seems to wait around until the native app has booted up

2) There is a full-screen white flash while React Native loads the components on the screen (I assume)

3) The app content starts loading (e.g. starts showing the loading spinners etc you have built into your components)

Step 2 feels a little glitchy. Is there a way of smoothing this out? Ideally it would be great to tell the native layer to only stop showing the launch image once your components have 'initialised' - is this possible?

Otherwise, are there any better ways of dealing with this? I notice other (usually native) apps usually don't behave this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was facing same issue, initially added native background color to the android activity to sort this out but it wasn't the best solution since i had multi shaded background therefore shifted to [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen)

Comment: Ahhhh good find! I'll try it out and let you know if it solves our issue.

Answer (score 0):

On which platform are you launching the app, iOS or Android?
In both cases there is a native background color on which the components are drawn. For example on Android the MainActivity's theme specified in the manifest determines the activity's background. This could explain the white flash in case you're running on Android.